# How to access a vector in a struct in C++?

Tags: c++

I was trying to access to my vector that I initialize in a struct, but when it compile, print this error:

> mediaselec.cc: In function 'void leeVector_conjunto(ConjuntoEstudiantes&)':
>       mediaselec.cc:23:4: error: 'ConjuntoEstudiantes' has no member named 'asignaturas'
>         v.asignaturas(num_asignaturas);

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Info{
    int id_student;       //id of a student
    vector<double> marks; //Contains all the marks of one student
};

//typedef vector<int> Subconjuntos;
typedef vector<Info> StudentGroup;

/*Read a vector of n student group*/
void enter_group(StudentGroup& v, Subconjuntos& s) {
    //Size of the StudentGroup
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    v = StudentGroup (n);
    //Num. marks of one student
    int num_marks;
    cin >> num_marks;

    //Ignore this part.
    /*
    //Numero de subconjuntos
    int s_subconjuntos;
    cin >> s_subconjuntos;
    s = Subconjuntos (s_subconjuntos);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> s[i]; 
    }
    */

    //Read all the students with all the marks and store it in v.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> v[i].id_student;
        for (int j = 0; j < num_marks; ++j) {
            cin >> v[i].marks[j];
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    StudentGroup v;
    //Subconjuntos s;
    enter_group(v,s);
}
```

Comment: The compiler is right,  'ConjuntoEstudiantes' has no member named 'asignaturas'. struct Info does.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I don't understand what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: Hi sergej, I try to do my best and translate my simple code. Well at the moment I just want to store in a vector a group of students, and each of those got num_marks. The problem is that I don't know if I'm doing a correct access to the vector in the struct.

Answer (score 0):

Where you wrote

```
v.asignaturas(num_asignaturas);
```

I think you intended

```
v[n].asignaturas.resize(num_asignaturas);
```

Edit:  When you edited to translate your variable names to English and to show more code, the line I was telling you to correct was removed.  But it is a necessary step.

Comment: You were right! thanks! I want to apologize my low english level.

Comment: Now i just add that line of code and all just works fine.